# Few queries regarding AWS instance connectivity and CPU utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a website running on AWS. The details are:

1. Instance type is m1.medium (it was t1.micro previously, recently upgraded to medium).
2. AMI: Ubuntu 12.04
3. Apache & PHP installed

The website is live and running smoothly and the website doesn't use any database yet except some PHP code and JavaScript. The website deals with displaying images but doesn't store images on the server. But the instance's Average CPU utilization graph is showing frequent spikes occurrence since the beginning. Screenshot can be viewed from [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apUXe.jpg).

We tried to run 'top' command using SSH as suggested in other threads here. But the problem is, when we hit enter after 'top' command, nothing is displayed; it hangs up. We tried with both the root and the default user.

Also, we are able to FTP and connect via SSH but not able to download/open files (but can add/delete files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to discover the what is running every minutes you can run `top` into a file

```
top -n 60 -b -d 60 > whats_running.txt
```

It will run 60 times in batch mode waiting 60 seconds between sampling

remember to run is as `root`

Answer (score 2):

From the graph it seems that the cpu load is consistently at 100% 2 times every hour (at :15 and :45).I suggest you check your crontab (on your users and root user) and see if there are any entries that might cause this.